# Char.Equals vs Object.Equals -- ReSharper suggests that I should use Object.Equals. Should I?

Tags: c#, object, char, resharper, object-equality

Basically, I'm wondering if I should listen to ReSharper in this instance...

You'd figure that comparing to characters one should use Char.Equals(char) since it avoids unboxing, but Resharper suggests using Object.Equals(obj). Maybe I'm missing something here?

---

```
private const DEFAULT_CHAR = '#';

// DependencyProperty backing
public Char SpecialChar
{
    get { return (Char)GetValue(SpecialCharProperty); }
}

// ReSharper - Access to a static member of a type via a derived type.
if (Char.Equals(control.SpecialChar, DEFAULT_CHAR)) { ... }
```

I'm guessing it's because there is a DependencyProperty backing?

Comment: The Equals from my understanding compares like things or unlike for example you would not say ObjectA == ObjectB you would check that using the ObjectA.Equals(ObjectB)

Comment: What's the actual line of code?  Does ReSharper give any reasoning for its suggestion?

Comment: my resharper does not suggest that :)

Comment: @Kyralessa: I added some code.

Comment: It's not because it's a dependency property, it's because you're calling a static method from `System.Object` via a descendant class (`System.Char`). ReSharper's warning message ("Access to a static member of a type via a derived type") makes that fairly clear, I think.

Comment: Consider the fact that your code works as expected if you replace `Char.Equals` with `Boolean.Equals`, 'System.Console.Equals`, `Uri.Equal`, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is impossible to override `static` members - `Object.Equals()` is a static member, and `Char` **cannot** override it, even though you can **call** it on the Char type (the params are still of type `Object`)

Therefore, it makes no difference whether you call

```
Object.Equals(object yourChar, object anotherChar)
```

or

```
Char.Equals(object yourChar, object anotherChar)
```

since boxing will occur in either case.

To avoid this, use the instance method, which **is overridden** in `Char`:

```
if (yourChar.Equals(anotherChar)) doSomething();
```

Comment: I would expect that resharper would suggest me to use the overridden instance version of `Equals`. Is this a bug or is it not possible to detect if there's an instance version of a static member via reflection?

Comment: see @Joe White's comment on the question - ReSharper is quite helpful, but it can't do *everything* for you. In fact, when I type `Char` and then `.Equ`, ReSharper seems to have overridden IntelliSense to **hide** `Object.Equals`...

Answer (score 5):

`Char.Equals(control.SpecialChar, DEFAULT_CHAR)` is a call to `Object.Equals(object, object)`, so resharper is correct here.

I would suggest to use 
`control.SpecialChar.Equals(DEFAULT_CHAR)` 
or just 
`DEFAULT_CHAR == control.SpecialChar`